# Finding \ guessing the antiderivative of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was given the following function:

$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 -|x|^{0.5}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1.5|x|^{0.5}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)& x\neq 0\\ 
 0&x=0 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

And I need to find the antiderivative on $\left[-1,0\right]$. I was trying to play with different variation and the closest I've got is:

$$
g(x)=-x^{1.5}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

which it's derivative is:

$$
g'(x)=x^{-0.5}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1.5x^{0.5}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

Is there a way to manipulate $g(x)$ to fit $f(x)$ or maybe there is a different function that gets the job done?

the exercise doesn't require to present the whole process so if anyone have a lucky guess it will be helpul too.

Comment: But does $x^{1.5}$ make sense when $x<0$? Are you sure there’s no typo in the question?

Comment: @TedShifrin Perhaps I should write it as $|x|^{1.5}$? Or maybe $(-x)^{1.5}$?

Comment: I still think there’s a typo. Where did this come from?

Comment: Yes, you should have used either $-x$ or $|x|$, just like the problem statement did. I agree with Ted Shifrin that there is a typo in the problem statement, but it is not in trying to take square roots of negative numbers - that was your mistake, not theirs. But other than that, the rest of your work is good. To get their result, you would need to find a closed form for the antiderivative of $$\left(\frac1{\sqrt{|x|}} + \sqrt {|x|}\right)\cos\frac 1x$$ which is not obvious, if such a closed form even exists. Likely, they accidently moved the negative from the exponent to in front.